# Is it possible to set variable name in bean injection?

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I have a jsf bean used in pretty much all jsf beans in the application and I prefer not to hardcode the bean name when injecting the bean instance. Is it possible make it a variable and use the variable everywhere?

```
@ManagedBean (name=ApplicationInfo.BEAN_NAME_APPLICATION_INFO, eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ApplicationInfo extends ParentBean
{
    public static final String      BEAN_NAME_APPLICATION_INFO="applicationInfo";
    .....
}
```

Now the referring class

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SearchResultsBean extends ParentBean
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @ManagedProperty (value="#{ApplicationInfo.BEAN_NAME_APPLICATION_INFO}")
    private ApplicationInfo applicationInfo;
    ....
}
```

Is it even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Do you realize that the `ApplicationInfo.BEAN_NAME_APPLICATION_INFO` part of your managed property value is a fully hardcoded string instead of a variable inlined in a string?

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, you can't set a variable name for a managed bean. 
Here you have the link to the docs of the ManagedBean annotation

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html

You can see that "Classes must be scanned for the presence of this annotation at application startup, before any requests have been serviced." 
So the name of the bean maybe only a hardcoded String. Every evaluation (such as calculate the value of ApplicationInfo.BEAN_NAME_APPLICATION_INFO) would happen later, when the application is started.